# How to make only windows from active desktop visible when in "Activities"?

Tags: gnome

When I go to the Activities-corner, all my windows from all my desktops becomes visible kind of like the scale plug-in works. However, I have many windows and I have my desktop well arranged and want only the windows from my currently active desktop to show up. How can I achieve this? I'm not afraid of hacking a bit, but I don't know where to start. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it isn't the known bug #844881.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/844881

When you go to Activities or press the [Windows]-button only applications from the current workspace should be visible. If some windows are displayed overlayed you are a victim of the obove described bug.

The only thing you can do then is press [Alt]+[F2] and type in `r` to restart Gnome Shell.

Comment: Yes. That is also a bug I'm affected by, but it is not related directly.

Most of the time the windows are displayed correctly, but all windows from all desktops always shows up.

That should be configurable somehow, like it is in the scale plugin for compiz in Gnome2

Comment: Actually, no. That was that bug, just very extreme. :D